# struts2 jquery remote tab and sj:div

Tags: jquery-plugins, struts2

```
<sj:tabbedpanel id="remotetabs" selectedTab="2" animate="true" 
  collapsible="true" sortable="true">
    <sj:tab id="tab1" href="myAction.action" label="Search"/>
</sj:tabbedpanel>
```

myAction.action.... returns jsp... with a form

```
<s:form id="searchForm"   >

  fields..........

 <sj:div  formIds="searchForm" href="test.jsp"  />

</s:form >
```

If I use IE 8, the div calls test.jsp with ajax and test.jsp gets the form parameters and returns fine.

Using FIREFOX, the div calls test.jsp with ajax BUT test.jsp *DOES NOT* get any of the form parameters, and returns.

WHY does test.jsp *NOT get the form parameters* using FIREFOX?

Answer (score 0):

fixed, had some malformed html. I guess firefox is stricter